# Missing numbers in the tables of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

So I have minor issue,
I have added:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Table des figures}
\listoffigures
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\printbibliography
```

and it works but, the thing is that in my `table of contents` or in the chapter 'title' the number does not show

How can I correct that?

Comment: Isn't doing `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` simpler than adding things by hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tocbibind` does not work together very well with `biblatex`, which is apparently used here (due to `\printbibliography`)

The numbered bibliography can be obtained with `\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered]`, the numbered list of figures requires a small redefinition and usage of `tocfile{...}{lof}`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}


\usepackage{biblatex}


\renewcommand{\listoffigures}{\begingroup
  \tocchapter
  \tocfile{\listfigurename}{lof}
\endgroup
}


\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\listoffigures

\cite{Lam94}
\printbibliography[heading={bibnumbered}]

\end{document}
```

[image]